# FileNet P8 cannot checkout a document

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-content-engine

I have an issue checking-out files in FileNet P8. It is possible for me to perform a checkout over documents with class "Document". Nevertheless, for any document from another class, the systems keeps telling me that the operation is not permitted.

On which level can I change this? Is it a basic document class property or is it over the Object Store parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is defined on class level if specific class is versionable. You should check if versioning is enabled for the class you work with:

[image]